# How do I query based on secondary indexes using dynamo db and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

How can I query using secondary index using dynamo db and node js

Heres my code so far, but it doesn't work

```
getObjectByAlternateKey: function (keyName, keyObj, indexName, callback, consistentRead) {
    var params = {
        TableName: this.tableName,
        KeyConditionExpression: keyName + ' = :v_key',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: converters.jsObjectToDynamoMap({ ':v_key': keyObj }),
        IndexName: indexName,
        ConsistentRead: !!consistentRead
    };
    this.dynamo.query(params, function (error, data) {
        console.dir(data);
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }
        if (data.Items && data.Items.length > 0) {
            if (data.Items.length !== 1) {
                console.warn("Got more than one item returned for query!", { query: params, data: data });
            }
            return callback(null, converters.dynamoMapToJsObject(data.Items[0]));
        }

        return callback(null, null);
    });
},
```

Here's the cloudformation template I used to create the table:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    "TableName": {
      "Description": "Table name to use",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "test-user-unique-ids-prod-ue1"
    },
    "ReadCapacityUnits": {
      "Description": "Provisioned read throughput",
      "Type": "Number",
      "Default": "100",
      "MinValue": "1",
      "MaxValue": "10000",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be between 1 and 10000"
    },
    "WriteCapacityUnits": {
      "Description": "Provisioned write throughput",
      "Type": "Number",
      "Default": "100",
      "MinValue": "1",
      "MaxValue": "10000",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be between 1 and 10000"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "sparkUserUniqueIds": {
      "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties": {
        "TableName": {
          "Ref": "TableName"
        },
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "guid",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "unique_id",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          }
        ],
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "guid",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          }
        ],
        "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
          {
            "IndexName": "test-user-by-unique-id",
            "KeySchema": [
              {
                "AttributeName": "unique_id",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
              }
            ],
            "Projection": {
              "ProjectionType": "ALL"
            },
            "ProvisionedThroughput": {
              "ReadCapacityUnits": {
                "Ref": "ReadCapacityUnits"
              },
              "WriteCapacityUnits": {
                "Ref": "WriteCapacityUnits"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
          "ReadCapacityUnits": {
            "Ref": "ReadCapacityUnits"
          },
          "WriteCapacityUnits": {
            "Ref": "WriteCapacityUnits"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give us the table description ? and if you got an error in your callback , could you mention it ?

Comment: see edit - I added additional details

Comment: Can you please helped me?

Answer (score 2):

Log your `params` value , it should be like this

```
{ TableName: 'test-user-unique-ids-prod-ue1',
  IndexName: 'test-user-by-unique-id',
  KeyConditions: 
   { unique_id: 
      { ComparisonOperator: 'EQ',
        AttributeValueList: [ { S: 'test' } ] } } }
```